# How to run a Tiger 10.4.11 virtual machine?

Tags: video, virtualization, powerpc, macos, firewire

I need to access some .omf files, which were originally created in an old version of AVID DV. As far as I know, this software only ran on Tiger PPC Macs. The PowerMac PPC G5 I originally used is on it's very last legs & will not reliably start up. An AVID rep told me that these old files would not be accessible with a current version of AVID and I have discovered that these files cannot be accessed with Final Cut Pro. What is my best option for getting this software running so I can access these OMF files in an AVID DV timeline?

What I have to work with:

- a white Intel Santa Rosa Macbook [3,1 - Build 9L31a] running Leopard
- the original MacBook Leopard install discs
- a variety of non-bootable disk image clones of a PPC G5 Tiger drive w/ AVID DV installed
- the dongle required for AVID DV to run
- the original G5 PPC Tiger install discs
- the original AVID DV install discs
- a Mountain Lion / Yosemite dual-boot Mac Mini
- a 2TB blank external USB drive
- a 1TB external Firewire drive that I can erase & reformat if necessary
- Parallels & Fusion for Mt. Lion

Comment: Can you provide the model number of the MacBook?

Comment: It is a MacBook 3,1 - Build 9L31a

Comment: Since it's running 10.5, it should have Rosetta, which allows Intel Macs to run PowerPC applications. Can you try and install AVID DV on it?

Comment: I can try, but my memory is that the issue with that was there not being enough space on the hard drive for it.

Comment: You may not legally virtualize Mac OS X Tiger 10.4.x as is it not allowed by its SLA and neither VMware, Parallels or VirtualBox can virtualize the PPC version of Mac OS X Tiger.

Comment: If I can't legally virtualize it, how can I simply run it on the hardware I have available?

Comment: @Kerlix, As far as I know the PPC version of Mac OS X Tiger will not run directly on an Intel Mac.

Answer (score -1):

You could try using the PearPC Emulator running on Linux or Win32 (Bootcamp?) to emulate a PPC and boot your drive images.

http://pearpc.sourceforge.net/installmacos.html

Comment: He can't use Boot Camp because his Mac mini is dual-booting Mountain Lion and Yosemite. Running the software under Rosetta should be much easier

Comment: To clarify, I'd create a Linux partition and within that install PearPC, which would be able to run one of the disk images I have the Tiger drive as well as access the DRM dongle?

Comment: I'm fine with wiping the Yosemite drive, if this would work.

Comment: Kerlix, I've not tried it.  But theoretically it should.  I don't know the limitations of PearPC and what features aren't implemented, sometimes DRM dongles can be a pain with emulation.